# Using complex numbers, can sine be greater than $1?$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I worked on a brain teaser that started with $\sin{(z)}=10.$ It then solved for $\cos{(z)}=\sqrt{-99}.$

I tried solving for $z,$ using $z=x+iy$ then $z=ae^{bi}$ but got nowhere. So is this even possible?

Comment: Yes. In fact, the only entire complex functions that are bounded are the constants. (Here, entire = analytic (in the complex sense) everywhere on $\mathbb{C}$. The $\sin$ function is entire.)

Comment: It's true that this shows that the (modulus of) the values of sine can be large, but it does not show that the sin itself ever takes on the value $10$. After all, $f(z) = \exp(z) + 10$ is unbounded, but *it* never takes on the value $10$.So it's something more subtle than being entire that makes this possible for sine.

Comment: [This](https://youtu.be/3C_XD_cCeeI) might be helpful

Comment: @JohnHughes: Yeah, that was more in the response to the question in the title rather than the one in the OP itself.

Comment: Ah...I see now. Now I'm wondering whether an entire function can miss the entire interval $1 < x < \infty$ of the real line. I suspect there's some obvious reason for an obvious answer, but it's been 40 years since I cracked open a complex-variables book, so...

Comment: @JohnHughes: No: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem .

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps not the "obvious" reason I anticipated (Picard had to prove the theorem, after all), but certainly a theorem I should have remembered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

For a complex number $z$, we have
\begin{align}
\sin z &= \frac{1}{2i}(\exp(iz) - \exp(-iz)) \\
\cos z &= \frac{1}{2}(\exp(iz) + \exp(-iz))
\end{align}
so in your problem, we have
\begin{align}
10 &= \frac{1}{2i}(\exp(iz) - \exp(-iz)) \\
10i &= \frac{1}{2}(\exp(iz) - \exp(-iz)) & \text{mult through by $i$}\\
i \sqrt{99} &= \frac{1}{2}(\exp(iz) + \exp(-iz))
\end{align}
Adding the last two equations gives us
$$
i(10 + \sqrt{99} = \exp{iz}
$$
so
$$
\log i(10 + \sqrt{99} ) = iz
$$
and hence
$$
z = \frac{\log (i(10 + \sqrt{99}) ) }{i}.
$$

Here "log" should be taken as the principal value of the natural logarithm (you may need to look this up!), and there's a second answer where we set the cosine to be $-i\sqrt{99}$, but I didn't bother writing it out.

Comment: Thanks John and @datboi

Comment: The $\sin z$ formula is written incorrectly here which leads to an incorrect result. The denominator should be $2i$ instead of $2$.

Comment: Thanks Vladmir. Re-doing the math means that 10 in the last equation becomes 10i, as in your answer above.

Comment: Good catch; now fixed (I think).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can.

Let us find such $z$ so that $\sin(z) = 10$.

Firstly, as a consequence of the Euler's formula:
$ e^{iz} = \cos(z) + i \cdot \sin(z)$,

we have the following two identities which hold for all complex numbers $z$:

$$
\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i} \\
\cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}
$$

Then:

$$
\sin(z) = 10 \\
\frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i} = 10 \\
e^{iz} - e^{-iz} - 20i = 0 \\
(e^{iz})^2 - 20i\cdot(e^{iz}) - 1 = 0 \\
$$

Solving the quadratic equation:

$$
\sqrt{D}=\sqrt{(-20i)^2 - 4 \cdot 1 \cdot (-1)} = \sqrt{-396} = 6i\sqrt{11} \\
(e^{iz}) = \frac{-(-20i) \pm \sqrt{D}}{2} = i \cdot (10 \pm 3\sqrt{11}) \\
$$

Complex logarithm:

$$
iz = Ln\left(i \cdot \left(10 \pm 3\sqrt{11}\right)\right) 
= \ln\left(i \cdot \left(10 \pm 3\sqrt{11}\right)\right) +
  i \cdot 2\pi k,
\qquad k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
iz = \ln(i) + \ln\left(10 \pm 3\sqrt{11}\right) + 2\pi ki \\
iz = \ln\left(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}\right) + 
  \ln\left(10 \pm 3\sqrt{11}\right) + 2\pi ki \\
iz = i\frac{\pi}{2} + \ln\left(10 \pm 3\sqrt{11}\right) + 2\pi ki \\
$$

The result:

$$
z = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k - i \cdot \ln\left(10 \pm 3\sqrt{11}\right),
\qquad k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

$\cos(z) = \sqrt{-99}$ can be solved in exactly the same way, giving the result:

$$
z = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k - i \cdot \ln\left(3\sqrt{11} \pm 10\right),
\qquad k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

The idea is taken from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3C_XD_cCeeI