# Plotting complex numbers when the angle is complex

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

A few months ago I asked about having a sine equal to 10; the answer was a complex number ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3844941/using-complex-numbers-can-sine-be-greater-than-1)).
I hoped to plot this on the usual 2-d complex plane, but couldn't figure out how.  Is there a way to graphically show complex trigonometry when the angle is complex?

Comment: What do you mean by "graphically show complex trigonometry"? I have three or four ideas which would require varying amounts of effort to write an answer for.

Comment: For trigonometry with real angles we visualize right triangles and points on the unit circle - I think the question is asking if there's something like that for the situation with complex "angles". I'm not aware of anything like this.

Comment: I think of trigonometric functions on $\Bbb C$ as the analytic continuations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) of the real versions, or as being defined by the identities $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ and $e^{-i\theta}=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$, which imply $\cos\theta=(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})/2$ and $\sin\theta=(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})/2i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to plot the sine function. Complex functions have 2-dimensional input and 2-dimensional output. You'd need 4 dimensions to accurately draw that graph. It's possible with an animation, but I don't think it's commonly done.

The standard approach, as far as I know, is to use color. You use the plane as input, and then you color each point in the plane according to the value of the output in polar coordinates. Black is 0, white is infinity, while hue is determined by the argument, with red along the positive real axis.

Here is a plot of the identity function $z\mapsto z$:

[image]

And here is the complex sine:

[image]

Both taken from [wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Complex_sin.jpg).

You can see along the real axis, that it's only red and cyan, between black dots. That's the regular real sine function. What you want are the vertical red lines, as those are the places where the sine function has positive real output greater than $1$. At some point those lines (which grow exponentially away from the real axis) are white enough to correspond to an absolute value of $10$, and that's where you have your solutions.

Comment: Wow. Nice, thank you.